# WSO2 DSS - Odata

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

When configuring a WSO2 DSS datasource, I have checked the 'Enable ODATA' option. I have verified that, ODATA endpoints are available for Oracle tables, but not Oracle views.

Does WSO2 DSS support for creating ODATA endpoints for Oracle views?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is not supported for Oracle views. You can use this [jira](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/DS-1276) ticket to track this improvement.